# Trouble with a bash script running as a systemd service restarting another systemd service the first time

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, systemd, systemctl

I've written a bash loop and named it freud.sh.

freud.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

while :
do
sleep 30
systemctl stop pacemaker
sleep 30
systemctl start pacemaker
done
```

Here is my unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Freud SplitBrain Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/root/utils/freud.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Systemd restarts the service the first time it tries to start the pacemaker service in the bash script (systemtl start pacemaker) as observed in 'journalctl -fu freud'

```
Jul 08 15:19:52 ENG_QA-HA2 systemd[1]: Started Freud SplitBrain Service.
Jul 08 15:19:53 ENG_QA-HA2 freud.sh[5460]: + :
Jul 08 15:19:53 ENG_QA-HA2 freud.sh[5460]: + sleep 30
Jul 08 15:20:23 ENG_QA-HA2 freud.sh[5460]: + systemctl stop pacemaker
Jul 08 15:20:26 ENG_QA-HA2 freud.sh[5460]: + sleep 30
Jul 08 15:20:39 ENG_QA-HA2 systemd[1]: Stopping Freud SplitBrain Service...
Jul 08 15:20:39 ENG_QA-HA2 systemd[1]: Stopped Freud SplitBrain Service.
Jul 08 15:20:39 ENG_QA-HA2 systemd[1]: Started Freud SplitBrain Service.
Jul 08 15:20:39 ENG_QA-HA2 freud.sh[6897]: + :
Jul 08 15:20:39 ENG_QA-HA2 freud.sh[6897]: + sleep 30
Jul 08 15:21:09 ENG_QA-HA2 freud.sh[6897]: + systemctl stop pacemaker
Jul 08 15:21:09 ENG_QA-HA2 freud.sh[6897]: + sleep 30
Jul 08 15:21:39 ENG_QA-HA2 freud.sh[6897]: + systemctl start pacemaker
Jul 08 15:21:39 ENG_QA-HA2 freud.sh[6897]: + :
```

It works the subsequent times as listed above, but in my "real" script, I've already passed that logic in the while loop which determines it needs to stop and start and it leaves the pacemaker service in a stopped state.

When I run the script in an ssh session or on cosole as a bash script, it works as desired.  Does anyone have any idea how to troubleshoot why the first attempt restarts my service?

Please let me know if you need more information.

EDITED:

```
[Unit]
Description=Pacemaker High Availability Cluster Manager
Documentation=man:pacemakerd
Documentation=https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html-single/Pacemaker_Explained/index.html

# DefaultDependencies takes care of sysinit.target,
# basic.target, and shutdown.target

# We need networking to bind to a network address. It is recommended not to
# use Wants or Requires with network.target, and not to use
# network-online.target for server daemons.
After=network.target

# Time syncs can make the clock jump backward, which messes with logging
# and failure timestamps, so wait until it's done.
After=time-sync.target

# Managing systemd resources requires DBus.
After=dbus.service
Wants=dbus.service

# Some OCF resources may have dependencies that aren't managed by the cluster;
# these must be started before Pacemaker and stopped after it. The
# resource-agents package provides this target, which lets system adminstrators
# add drop-ins for those dependencies.
After=resource-agents-deps.target
Wants=resource-agents-deps.target

After=syslog.service
After=rsyslog.service
After=corosync.service
Requires=corosync.service


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


[Service]
Type=simple
KillMode=process
NotifyAccess=main
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/pacemaker
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/sbd
SuccessExitStatus=100

ExecStart=/usr/sbin/pacemakerd -f

# Uncomment TasksMax if your systemd version supports it.
# Only systemd v227 and above support this option.
#TasksMax=infinity

# If pacemakerd doesn't stop, it's probably waiting on a cluster
# resource.  Sending -KILL will just get the node fenced
SendSIGKILL=no

# If we ever hit the StartLimitInterval/StartLimitBurst limit and the
# admin wants to stop the cluster while pacemakerd is not running, it
# might be a good idea to enable the ExecStopPost directive below.
#
# Although the node will likely end up being fenced as a result so it's
# not on by default
#
# ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/killall -TERM crmd attrd stonithd cib pengine lrmd

# If you want Corosync to stop whenever Pacemaker is stopped,
# uncomment the next line too:
#
# ExecStopPost=/bin/sh -c 'pidof crmd || killall -TERM corosync'

# Uncomment this for older versions of systemd that didn't support
# TimeoutStopSec
# TimeoutSec=30min

# Pacemaker can only exit after all managed services have shut down
# A HA database could conceivably take even longer than this
TimeoutStopSec=30min
TimeoutStartSec=60s

# Restart options include: no, on-success, on-failure, on-abort or always
Restart=on-failure

# crm_perror() writes directly to stderr, so ignore it here
# to avoid double-logging with the wrong format
StandardError=null
```

Including the contents of the unit file for the pacemaker service.  What's interesting is that using the command "pcs maintenance node $HOSTNAME" has the same behavior, so I'm starting to think you're on to something that the pacemakerd process may be causing this and not systemd.

Any idea how to troubleshoot?

MORE EDIT:

Further investigation with strace has determined that pacemaker is forking and causing the systemd service to stop.  Or atleast that's the way it was explained to me by the developer.  Again, any help is appreciated.

```
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: write(2, "+ pcs node maintenance ENG_QA-HA"..., 34+ pcs node maintenance ENG_QA-HA2
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: ) = 34
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: stat("/usr/local/sbin/pcs", 0x7fffec2c6530) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: stat("/usr/local/bin/pcs", 0x7fffec2c6530) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: stat("/usr/sbin/pcs", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=292, ...}) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: stat("/usr/sbin/pcs", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=292, ...}) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: geteuid()                               = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: getegid()                               = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: getuid()                                = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: getgid()                                = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: access("/usr/sbin/pcs", X_OK)           = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: stat("/usr/sbin/pcs", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=292, ...}) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: geteuid()                               = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: getegid()                               = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: getuid()                                = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: getgid()                                = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: access("/usr/sbin/pcs", R_OK)           = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: stat("/usr/sbin/pcs", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=292, ...}) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: stat("/usr/sbin/pcs", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=292, ...}) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: geteuid()                               = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: getegid()                               = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: getuid()                                = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: getgid()                                = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: access("/usr/sbin/pcs", X_OK)           = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: stat("/usr/sbin/pcs", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=292, ...}) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: geteuid()                               = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: getegid()                               = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: getuid()                                = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: getgid()                                = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: access("/usr/sbin/pcs", R_OK)           = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [INT CHLD], 8) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [INT CHLD], NULL, 8) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f188e823a10) = 32205
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x43e860, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f188de513b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f188de513b0}, 8) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 32205
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=32205, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=11, si_stime=2} ---
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: wait4(-1, 0x7fffec2c5f50, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f188de513b0}, {0x43e860, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f188de513b0}, 8) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: write(2, "+ sleep 90\n", 11+ sleep 90
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: )            = 11
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f188e823a10) = 32411
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:13 ENG_QA-HA2 strace[27232]: rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x43e860, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f188de513b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f188de513b0}, 8) = 0
Jul 15 10:43:26 ENG_QA-HA2 systemd[1]: Stopping Freud SplitBrain Service...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's not Pacemaker doing this on startup?

Comment: You are absolutely right.  PCS is forking itself and that's what is stopping the systemd service.  Do you know anyway to fix this or work around it?

Comment: Forking is not what's stopping the service; a service can fork all it wants. What's stopping the service is something that the forked child _does in between_ the clone() and the wait4(). If you run strace with the `-f` or `-f -e execve` option, you will likely see that PCS is doing the standard fork+exec routine in order to call an external command -- i.e. it is probably just calling `system("systemctl stop freud")` or something similar. Which makes it a PCS configuration issue and not really a service management issue.

Comment: Not sure how to award you points, but you were definitely helpful in finding the workaround.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, come to think of it, your strace isn't even about pcs forking; it actually shows the *shell script interpreter* forking. Which is quite normal for a shell to do (it has to fork & exec the commands, after all), and matches up with the output being written to stderr. But it reveals nothing about what *those tools* are doing internally – you really need the `-f` for that.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around the problem by writing a sentinel file and only stopping pacemaker when conditions are met.  When systemd starts the service back up, it checks for the file at the beginning and runs a start on pacemaker if it detects it.  Probably a better way of handling this, but the problem is technically solved and I can move on until a better solution is discovered.  Thanks for all the help!